# Purchase failed because Purchasing was not initialized correctly

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

In Unity3D, my in-App purchasing works, displaying the test environment in app purchasing question. However, when I upload it to xcode and run it, it gives me an error.

I'm using an IAP Button, the codeless version. I've entered my Apple SKU, Team ID, and override for the AppleStoreID, but it still gives me this error:

```
IAPButton.PurchaseProduct() with product ID: No Ads Subscription
UnityEngine.Purchasing.IAPButton:PurchaseProduct()
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction'1) 

UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)

Purchase failed because Purchasing was not initialized correctly
UnityEngine.Purchasing.CodelessIAPStoreListener:InitiatePurchase(String)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug.bindings.h Line: 45)

IAPButton.OnPurchaseFailed(Product , PurchaseFailureReason PurchasingUnavailable)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.IAPButton:OnPurchaseFailed(Product, PurchaseFailureReason)
UnityEngine.Purchasing.CodelessIAPStoreListener:InitiatePurchase(String)
UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent:Invoke()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents:Execute(GameObject, BaseEventData, EventFunction`1)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchPress(PointerEventData, Boolean, Boolean)
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:ProcessTouchEvents()
UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule:Process()
```

I've already turned on In App Purchasing in Unity, and enabled it in Xcode, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Are you testing on a real device?

Answer (score 2):

Make you complete your **Apple Tax and Banking Agreement** (especially paid Apps), they must be **active**.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In My Case It Was Bundle Identifier(package name) Make sure you have exact same package as on Appstore.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).